# How do I use bearer tokens with regular not-ajax requests?

Tags: owin, nancy

I might be going nuts... I have the Nancy.StatelessAuth Owin middleware for validating JWTs in the Authorization header of cross-domain ajax requests.

But before I get to there, I would like to show some simple web pages to locally logged-in users, reusing, if possible, the same authorization pipeline.

I have a login page returning a JWT cookie, as recommended by Stormpath. For ajax, I can easily set the Authorization header in javascript, pulling the value from the cookie. But for regular web pages, I would like the StatelessAuth middleware to pull the token from the cookie. Is this reasonable? Do I need to write a middleware upstream of StatelessAuth to pull the token from the cookie and put it in a header, as [this thing](https://github.com/VQComms/Owin.QueryStringToHeader) does for query strings?

Answer (score 0):

Ok for the moment, [this seems to be a much more reasonable approach](http://blog.jonathanchannon.com/2015/04/27/cookie-authentication-angularjs-csrf-owin-mono/). I'll have cookie middleware for locally logged users accessing pages, and jwt middleware for cross domain services, then a backstop to lock out requests that are cookieless and tokenless and not whitelisted.